# Windows 10 store is acting strnage

Tags: windows-10-mobile, store, lumia-640-xl

Everything was fine till yesterday, when out of the blue, the store doesn't work properly. Here is the problem:

The store doesn't open full page of apps. rarely it does, but most of the time, I cannot go past the "people also like" screen. So cannot see the revisions of the app and the ratings and reviews, and system requirements. This never happened before. I didn't install any new app or change some settings. In my father's mobile, also running windows 10 same version, this doesn't happen. I tried restart, soft reset. Neither helped. I have to stay at the page for some time and only then I can go past the screen. What's wrong? Tried it many times.

YES, my internet is working fine at 10Mbps.

Comment: There was an update to the Store app around 24th Jan - do you have it installed?

Comment: I think it's normal, the bottom part always takes longer to load for me as well

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes, it is updated.

Comment: @miguelmpn Maybe. But it always loaded faster for me.